# determining vicinity between character lists

Tags: python, search

I have a list of ~300,000 keywords (both single and multiple words) and another list of single words. I also have ~1200 files containing text in multiple lines. I need to check if in any of the files, there are words of both these lists near each other. By vicinity, I mean the two words are about 10 words apart or less.
An example of a string from the first list is `NOD.BDC2.5 transgenic mice` and from the other list is `inhibition`.

Any ideas? I have searched extensively but cannot find anything. Also, since these are multi-word strings, I cannot use abs(array.index) for the two (which was possible with single words).

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify about single and multiple words and vicinity of them.

Comment: first list has around 300000 'phrases' whereas second has around 30 'words'. By vicinity, I mean they are closer than 10 words to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simplify the problem by solving it in chunks. First, loop over the file having the sentences, then check if a line has any words from your second file `file2` as it has fewer entries. If it does, then check for the presence of words from the first file `file1`.

now, break the line into its constituent words using `re.split` function. Find the index of the first word for the two entries and subtract the to see if they are closer than 10 words. This must be easy since your second list has only single word strings.

Here is the sample code -

```
for s in sentences:
            s = s.rstrip()
                if f2 in s:  # f1 is an entry from file2
                    l = re.split(';|,|-| ', s) # split the line by comma, semicolon and space 
                    for f1 in file1: 
                        f1 = f1.rstrip()     #remove lagging whitespace characters                   
                        
                        if f1 in s: # search for f1 in line
                                                      
                            if ((f1 in l) and (f2 in l)): # ensure both are in the list                                                                                            
                                                             
                                r = abs(l.index(f1) - l.index(f2)) # find distance between first character of f1 and f2
                                if r<=10:
                                        match found
```

Comment: this is impressive. thanks for the explanation. let me try it